# Borderless UIButton that highlights when touched

Tags: iphone

I'd like to create a UIButton with an image that has no borders (a la UIButtonTypeInfoDark) but that highlights when you tap it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a UIButton in interface builder, change the type to custom (and select your image). Add an IBOutlet, then in your viewDidLoad set showsTouchWhenHighlighted to YES.